# the ECDSA host key for 'xx' differs from the key for the IP address 'xx

Tags: networking, ssh, dhcp, networkmanager

I get this warning often because a computer is using DHCP and is getting a different IP than before. I know how to deal with it on a case-by-case base but would like to understand the appropriate permanent solution. I see possible approaches, but what is "best practice"?

- insert host *.local

  `StrictHostKeyChecking no`

  in ~/.config/ssh. Not tried, but was told that only a warning will be produced.
- assign a "static" IP on the router for the MAC address of the computer; must be repeated for each router manually...
- assign a static IP with `Network manager`..
- assign a static IP as primary but allow e DHCP service as a fallback position? i.e. use the static IP if possible and DHCP only if not possible, e.g. because the subnet is different? Here my understanding ends... How does `Network manager` select between different static addresses?

I have read multiple posts on related topics but could not find a recommendation with a good justification.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is to *reserve* ip-addresses by MAC-address in the DHCP-daemon, which basically makes these static. How that is done depends on what system the service is running on.

Comment: Thank you, happy to hear your experience. I did something similar for some machines - but I have two routers and keep them in sync is difficult. no CLI on the router. The router GUI calls this "static"! The duplication has been occasionally  a source of confusion.